# how to send html formatted text to text filed in template docusign?

Tags: php, docusignapi

hi i want to send bullet point to docusign template text field
but when i send it as a html it will print as it is, even the `[\r\n][1]` is not working how i can send the formatted text so i can you the bullet points

this is the text i want to show in format

```
<ol><li>this is the test term </li><li>this is the test term again </li><li>this is the last term for testing purpose</li></ol>
```

[text field in template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xa4C.png)

[this is the way i want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chYJH.png)

[this is the way its being shown right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFJuj.png)

**updated**

how add new line using Unicode ?

**updated 18-Nov-2020**

I want the answer for PHP language please , using docusign SDK

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The DocuSign text fields can only handle plain text, not HTML.

But good news: that includes all Unicode characters including Unicode bullet points such as this triangular bullet point: ‣

So your application can add bullet points to DocuSign text fields.

As an alternative, your application could create a custom document for the envelope in addition to or instead of the template's document(s).

You could create the additional document using HTML or create a PDF document on the fly.

### Added (and updated)

Tested! It works! To add a new line, I add new line character to the text tab's value.

If your computer language interpolates character sequences, that'd be

```
value = "‣   line 1\n‣   line 2"
```

Working Node.JS example:

```
    ...
    let textTab1 = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/sig1/",  
        anchorXOffset: "120",  
        height: "30",  
        value: "‣   line 1\n‣   line 2",  
        width: "120" 
        });
    let textTabs1 = [textTab1];
    let tabs1 = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        signHereTabs: signHereTabs1,  
        textTabs: textTabs1 
        });
    ...
```

Result (screenshot):

[image: screenshot showing two lines of text in text tab]

Comment: what about the new line how i can print new line
1. Bullet point 1 <new line>
2. Bullet point 2 <new line>
3. Bullet point 3 <new line>

@larry K

Comment: Try a new line character

Comment: can you give me the code new line character you mean \n\r ?

Comment: as i said in the question i already try this. docusign just take this as a string it does not support special character like break line or new line like \n\r \n

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. See updated section, above.